# What is the meaning of 'for _ in range()

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm looking at some tensorflow stuff and I understand for loops or atleast I think I do, however I came across `for _ in range(20)` and was wondering what is the meaning of the _ in this case. I am used to for x in range or for i in range stuff and understand those but haven't been able to understand what i've read on the underscore

Comment: By convention `_` means to other developers that the variable is unused. On that note linters such as pylint will not emit "unused variable" warnings for this symbol.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you are not interested in some values returned by a function we use underscore in place of variable name . Basically it means you are not interested in how many times the loop is run till now just that it should run some specific number of times overall.

Comment: *"it means you are not interested in how many times the loop is run"* is not true. I think a better sentence would be *"we don't care about the iterator value, just that it should run some specific number of times".*